# Reactjs, re-render same components, but different return data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

A little hard to explain, but please bear with me.

I have this `function Component`. The `function Component` code is almost the same, but how can i simplify my `function MyComponent` with the `return` value are different to each pages?

Below is my code and to better understand here is the complete sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-same-components-different-return-fm5v7).

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=nature?orientation=landscape&client_id=ddIh7_ebg4KwNHzNLf3ePCZb6yIPREJ5jxG3dYgoj6U"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.results);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
        This return has to be dynamic. See the function Home and About below.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Here is my Home and About pages.

```
function Home() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.user.last_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.user.first_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`MyComponent` doesn't appear to be rendered in my codesandbox, thats why im asking how can achieve my questions.

Comment: `MyComponent` doesn't appear to be rendered anywhere in your codesandbox. The other two components are rendering with empty arrays. It's unclear what you are asking or what any issue is.

Comment: yes you are right MyComponent doesn't appear to be rendered in my codesandbox , thats why im asking how can achieve my question above.thx dude.

Comment: Uh, and what is the question? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: In my sandbox if your are in the Home page I want to display the list of {item.user.last_name} from the fetch API and if you are in the About page I want to display the {item.user.first_name} from the fetch API and it will show below the <h2> tag of eact page. Let me know if you are confused:)

Comment: Does `MyComponent` need to be a separate component? In other words, can you just move all of the component logic into `App` and pass data down as props to the routed components? Are there any restrictions? Or is the goal simply to get the `items` data to the two routed components?

Comment: just put `<MyComponent />` on place, where you want to render it...

Comment: The goal is to get the items data to the two routed components, because im going to put the functions Home and About inside components folder and import it to the App.  Btw the sandbox have already updated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you've no centralized source of truth. Each of `MyComponent`, `Home`, and `About` each have their own `items` state. The question you are asking is how to get the `items` that `MyComponent` fetched passed to the other two.

The solution is to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Move all the fetching and rendering logic from `MyComponent` into `App`. Pass the `items` state down to both `Home` and `About`.

App

```
export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=nature?orientation=landscape&client_id=ddIh7_ebg4KwNHzNLf3ePCZb6yIPREJ5jxG3dYgoj6U"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setItems(result.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {<Layout />}
      <main>
        {error ? (
          <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
        ) : !isLoaded ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <React.Suspense fallback={<h6>Loading...</h6>}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home items={items} />} />
              <Route path="/about" element={<About items={items} />} />
            </Routes>
          </React.Suspense>
        )}
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Home

```
function Home({ items }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.user.last_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

About

```
function About({ items }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.user.first_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit reactjs-re-render-same-components-but-different-return-data]